# How to combine row and column name of df when value in target cell of df is not NA

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dataset, data-cleaning

I have a df like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(c(3,NA,5), c(NA, NA, 3), c(3, 2, NA))
names(df1) <- c('number1', 'number2', 'number3')
rownames(df1) <- c('siteA', 'siteB', 'siteC')
```

I want to make a new df where row and column name are combined from the values that are not NA. The resulting df should look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame('number' = c('number1', 'number1', 'number2', 'number3', 'number3'), 
                  'site' = c('siteA', 'siteC', 'siteC', 'siteA', 'siteB'))
```

How do I do this as efficiently as possible? (my real df is massive)

Comment: There may context-dependent optimizations that you would consider if reducing run-time is that much of a priority. For example, if the "data frame" is a handle to a table in a database, then letting the database do as much work as possible will probably be to your advantage.

Comment: if the types of the columns you're checking are all identical, then something like `mx %>% apply(2, is.finite) %>% apply(2, which)` may be fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a matrix or table each axis can have a name which is a character string labelling that axis. Convert df1 to a matrix m and add those.

Then convert that to long form using `as.data.frame.table` and remove the rows with NA's.  `as.data.frame.table` will add a third column named `Freq` which we don't need so select out the first 2 columns only and since the question put number first reverse the order of the two columns extracted.

```
 m <- as.matrix(df1)
 names(dimnames(m)) <- c("site", "number")

 m |>
  as.data.frame.table() |>
  na.omit() |>
  subset(select = 2:1)
##    number  site
## 1 number1 siteA
## 3 number1 siteC
## 6 number2 siteC
## 7 number3 siteA
## 8 number3 siteB
```

`m` looks like this.  Note the dimnames.

```
m
##        number
## site    number1 number2 number3
##   siteA       3      NA       3
##   siteB      NA      NA       2
##   siteC       5       3      NA
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way using `tidyverse`:

```
df1 %>% 
    rownames_to_column('site') %>%
    pivot_longer(-site, names_to = 'number', values_to = 'value') %>%
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
    select(-value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `which()` here. First you find where there are non missing rows in the data.frame (don't need to convert it to a matrix first) and get the indicies with `arr.ind = TRUE`. These indicies are the rows and columns for your data with non-NA values. An added benefit of which is that the row.names will be the row.names of the original `data.frame` . I convert the matrix output to a data.frame with the correct variable names and then assign the numbers the values from the column and row names.

```
df2 <- which(!is.na(df1), arr.ind = TRUE)

df2 <- data.frame(number =colnames(df1)[df2[,2]] , site = row.names(df2))
```

Benchmark for fun:

```
transform_fn <- function(){
  m <- as.matrix(df1)
  names(dimnames(m)) <- c("site", "number")
  
  m |>
    t() |>
    as.data.frame.table() |>
    na.omit() |>
    subset(select = 1:2)
}

which_fn <- function(){
df2 <- which(!is.na(df1), arr.ind = TRUE)

 data.frame(number =colnames(df1)[df2[,2]] , site = row.names(df2))
}

tidyverse_fn <- function(){df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column('site') %>%
  pivot_longer(-site, names_to = 'number', values_to = 'value') %>%
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  select(-value)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(which_fn(),transform_fn(),tidyverse_fn(),
                               times = 1000)
```

[image: benchmarkresults]

Answer (score 1):

We can try `expand.grid` + `dimnames`

```
> rev(expand.grid(dimnames(df1)))[!is.na(unlist(df1)), ]
     Var2  Var1
1 number1 siteA
3 number1 siteC
6 number2 siteC
7 number3 siteA
8 number3 siteB
```